# Retrive the total amout of money spend on the site by a customer with Soap

Tags: customer, soap, sales

My question is quite simple.
On the web interface, when I edit one customer: Clients > Client Information > Client View
In the Sales statistics the filed "Sales from the begining" interests me. It tells how much the client has spent on the site since it exists.
I would like to retrive this value with SOAP does anyone knows how to do it ?
I've checked the API documentation but didn't find this value.
So far I'm able to do simple tasks with my SOAP script: list all customer, list one customer information...So my question is not about how to program or make Magento accessible with web services.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, there is no way to retrieve this information via the Magento SOAP API.

If you want to extend the SOAP API, the Information shown in the backend is retrieved as follows:

Block: `adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_sales`

Template: `app/ design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view/sales.phtml`

Check for the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->formatCurrency($this->getTotals()->getBaseLifetime()) ?>
```